# Write and read nested objects in a database in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to get nested items from my database and can't figure out how.

My database looks like:

```
GET /dwelling/room/


[
    {
        "room_id": 1,
        "room_name": "Living Room",
        "room_data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "temperature": "5,15,9"
                ...
```

I am currently using:

```
    fetch('https://.../dwelling/room/', {
      method: 'GET',
    }).then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(resp => this.setState({room: resp}))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

to get the data from the database as well as

```
{props.room.map(room => {

                return (

                    <React.Fragment>
                        <div>{room.room_name}<div>
                    </React.Fragment>
                    ...
```

I am able to get the data for room_id and room_name but cannot get anything from inside room_data. I want to be able to put the temperature into a graph but I can't even get the data to print out in a list. I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your record, you can get **room temprature** by simply accessing `room.room_data[0].temperature`

```
[
    {
        "room_id": 1,
        "room_name": "Living Room",
        "room_data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "temperature": "5,15,9"
                ...
```

Comment: pls don't forget to upvote this answer..